# Doubly Linked List Error

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

So, I'm trying to do operations in a doubly linked list, and I tried applying the logic of deletion but it's showing some sort of void error. Please tell me what's wrong in this code. 
The error message is written alongside the line of code.

Function to get new node:

```
void getnewnode(int x)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
}
```

Insert function:

```
void insertatbeg(int x)
{
    struct node* newnode=getnewnode(x); /* void value not ignored as it ought to be. */
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = newnode;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
}
```

Delete(nth node) function:

```
void delete(int n)
{
    struct node* temp1=head;
    int i;
    if(temp1 == NULL)
        return;
    for(i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    struct node* temp2 = temp1->next;
    (temp2->next)->prev = temp1;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    free(temp2);
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
struct node /* List called node */
{            
    struct node* next;
    int data;
    struct node* prev;
};

struct node* head;

void insertatbeg(int x);
void delete(int n);
int main()
{    
    int x;
    head = NULL;
    insertatbeg(x);
    insertatbeg(x);
    insertatbeg(x);
    delete(2);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Comment: And please post the exact error message.

Comment: the function: `getnewnode()` seems to be critical to debugging the problem.  and `delete()` has nothing to do with the problem so why post it?  Please post the code for: `getnewnode()`;

Comment: The title might be more informative, so it could possibly help future readers.

Comment: Added the `getnewnode()` function as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me your problem is here:

```
void getnewnode(int x)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
}
```

Specifically, in the first line. You probably want that to be `sizeof(struct node)`, so that your pointer references a node, not a pointer to a node.

You also need to make your function return a value. So change it to:

```
void getnewnode(int x)
{
    ....
    return temp;
}
```

The reason you're getting the error on this line:

```
struct node* newnode=getnewnode(x); /* void value not ignored as it ought to be. */
```

Is that your `getnewnode` function doesn't return a value. So `newnode` can't be assigned a value. That error should go away when you make the suggested change to `getnewnode()`.

Comment: Well, I added the return statement as you suggested. But, it's still showing the same error. Weird, I guess.

Comment: @KartikV: What is the *exact* error message the compiler outputs?